# Using jQuery as a dev tool

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have a lot of static pages that I want to edit in some uniform manner, rename or adding classes for example. Now, jQuery allows me to do such operations in a manner that I'm very familiar with, but on the client side. Now I would like to do this in development; pick up a static web page, change something using jquery and save it again to disk. Is there a simple way to set up jQuery (and probably node.js) to allow this?

Comment: jQuery works on the level of DOM, not text, so this approach would look like HTML -> DOM -> (work) -> DOM -> HTML which could possibly lose some information in the translation.

Comment: That would not be optimal, unless you are scraping the web. You can use templates for this, dynamically passing an view object and rendering the page from it.

Comment: what about this http://nodize.com/

Comment: Set up nodeJS with the [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) package.

Comment: What kind of information would be lost in such translation @Kos? If the html is well formed it should come through the same? Give or take some whitespace?

Comment: @worldsayshi Whatever isn't a part of the DOM. Comments, maybe some syntax nuances that a parser didn't catch (graceful degradation etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it using jquery for node**
https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery

// install

```
npm install jquery
```

// usage:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var inputHtml = '<html><body></body></html>';

var $html = $(inputHtml);

/* change background to red */
$html.find('body').css('background-color', 'red');

/* get back html string*/
var outputHtml = $html.find('body').parent()[0].outerHTML;

console.log(outputHtml);
```

//console

```
$ node jquery-test
<html><body style="background-color: red;"></body></html>
```

node-jquery is slow, and not async, do not call it directly in side http handler, but it is good for webcrawler, and offline processing.

Comment: Hmm, changing css properties shouldn't effect the html? I got your point though. Thanks! This would probably be a  better example operation: `$html.find('body').addClass('myClass');`

Comment: I have just modified the example code, it work on my computer, windows8, node#0.10.20, jquery#1.8.3

Answer (score 2):

You can use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) at your server side.

More answers here: [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)