# Basic error when using jquery with nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js

I'm trying to use some jquery in my project and as soon as I tried using it I came across an error in copied code and can't get any google help on it

```
 var jquery = require('jquery');
 var $ = jquery.create();
                ^
 TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
     if ( !w.document ) {
          throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
     }
     return factory( w );
 } has no method 'create'
```

Long story:

I'm trying to get plaintext from some html I have.

I hope to use `.text()` function which supposedly does that.

My resulting code should be:

```
console.log($(data).text());
```

Comment: You're probably doing the wrong thing entirely.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) library?

Comment: I added 
    "jquery":">= 0.0.0",
to my dependencies

Comment: It seems that you are using jQuery on the server side (so inside node.js) and jQuery tries to find the document of the browser window. But since you are not running inside a browser it can not find any document. I am afraid SLaks comment is spot on.

Comment: are you running on windows (OS)

Comment: yes, I'm running on windows 7. what 341613 said makes perfect sense. What confuses me is am I not supposed to be able to use jquery serverside?

Comment: make sure that is the right jquery: `npm install jquery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use jquery on server as it explicitly requires `window` and `window.document`. Try [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio)

Comment: Yeah. Seems like I can't. Unfortunately cheerio doesn't have something simple for html->plaintext but I'll keep looking

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense to me. What is the use of having a jQuery module for Node.js if it can't be used server-side? I mean, if I want to use it client-side then I'll just include it on the page.

Comment: so, there is no jQuery for Node.js, that's the problem. The fact that it's on npm doesn't make it Node.js module.

Comment: There are libraries which allow you to use jQuery on the server side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var markup = '<html><body><h1 class="example">Hello World!</h1><p class="hello">Heya Big World!</body></html>';
var doc = jsdom(markup);
var window = doc.parentWindow;
var $ = require('jquery')(window)
console.log($('.example').text());
```

Basically you can use the jsdom module to create a DOM out of your markup and then you can use it as you would with jquery in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for line 5 `var $ = require('jquery')(window)` that's postponed my trip to the jQuery Insane Asylum by a couple of weeks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To solve it I installed an older version of jquery:
`npm install jquery@1.8.3`