# How to use npm jquery module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

How should I `require`the `jquery` in `node` if I use it in multiple modules? Should I define it as a global or should I just use the `require('jquery`)` in every module I need it?

I am getting an error when trying to use the package.

```
TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        } has no method 'isArray'
```

It looks like a bug in the current release as it should not check if I am running it in a browser according to the official documentation. This issue is also mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832470/basic-error-when-using-jquery-with-nodejs). It works with version `1.8.3` as mentioned in one of the answers.

Answer (score 23):

To use jquery in node, you need to have two separate node package installations.

1. jquery
2. jsdom to create a dummy window object which jquery can use.

Installation:

```
npm install jquery
npm install jsdom
```

In code:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
global.$ = require('jquery/dist/jquery')(jsdom().createWindow());
```

Or, with newer versions of jsdom:

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```

Using global.$ will make the jquery object($) available globally in your project.

Answer (score 19):

You can use as below to handle as usual:

```
var $;
$ = require('jquery');
$('.tag').click(function() {
  return console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: This works well for Node.js. And if you're on TypeScript, don't forget to `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery`.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, this helped a lot.