# React-router server-side error

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make my client-side webapp isomorphic.
I get this as a pattern: [Client Routing (using react-router) and Server-Side Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553904/client-routing-using-react-router-and-server-side-routing)

Here what i've got.

server.js:

```
var React = require('react'),
express = require('express'),
Router = require('react-router'),
routes = require('./src/js/main'),
path = require('path'),
app = express(),
port = 5555,
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Make sure to include the JSX transpiler
require("node-jsx").install();

// Include static assets. Not advised for production
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
// Set view path
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// set up ejs for templating. You can use whatever
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// ...express config...

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var router = Router.create({location: req.url, routes: routes})
  router.run(function(Handler, state) {
    var reactHtml = React.renderToString(<Handler/>)
    return res.render('index.ejs', {reactOutput: reactHtml})
  })
})

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server is Up and Running at Port : ' + port);
```

main.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Link = Router.Link;
var APPLICATION_ID = '',
    SECRET_KEY = '',
    VERSION = 'v1'; //default application version;
Backendless.initApp(APPLICATION_ID, SECRET_KEY, VERSION);



// wrapper
APP = require('./components/app').APP;

// pages
var Frontpage = require('./components/frontpage/app-frontpage'); // homepage
var NewEstate = require('./components/new-estate/app-newestate');
var NewEstateDetails = require('./components/new-estate/app-newestatedetails');
var Contacts = require('./components/static/app-contacts');
var About = require('./components/static/app-about');

var SecondEstate = require('./components/second-estate/app-secondestate');
var SecondEstateDetails = require('./components/second-estate/app-secondestatedetails');
var CommerceEstate = require('./components/commerce-estate/app-commerceestate');
var CommerceEstateDetails = require('./components/commerce-estate/app-commerceestatedetails');



var routes = (
  <Route handler={APP}>
    <Route handler={Frontpage}/>
    <Route name="NewEstate" ignoreScrollBehavior={true} handler={NewEstate}/>
    <Route name="NewEstateDetails" ignoreScrollBehavior={true} path="/NewEstate/:itemId" params={{routeType: "NewEstateDetails" }} handler={NewEstateDetails}/>
    <Route name="SecondEstate" ignoreScrollBehavior={true} handler={SecondEstate}/>
    <Route name="SecondEstateDetails" ignoreScrollBehavior={true} path="/SecondEstate/:itemId" params={{routeType: "SecondEstateDetails" }} handler={NewEstateDetails}/>
    <Route name="CommerceEstate" ignoreScrollBehavior={true} handler={CommerceEstate}/>
    <Route name="CommerceEstateDetails" ignoreScrollBehavior={true} path="/CommerceEstate/:itemId" params={{routeType: "CommerceEstateDetails" }} handler={NewEstateDetails}/>
    <Route name="Contacts" handler={Contacts}/>
    <Route name="About" handler={About}/>    
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('main'));
});
```

and index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Балкит - Агентство недвижимости</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body >
<div id="main"><%- reactOutput %><div class=""></div></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA7F9cOuVNV6_RRAdLowrz9elBbRuXFy2Y&libraries=drawing"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to run server.js and getting this error:

```
//web/react-balkit/server.js:28
    var reactHtml = React.renderToString(<Handler/>)
                                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

I've tried to fix it, but i'm getting further from the pattern and getting more errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `require("node-jsx").install();` is inserting middleware that transforms any JSX into vanilla JS.

However, you are requiring a file with JSX syntax **before** this is included. As with all middleware, order is important.

To fix, insert them the other way round:

`require("node-jsx").install();
routes = require('./src/js/main')`

**EDIT: Addition for server**

You can create a factory in order to use standard JS.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var router = Router.create({location: req.url, routes: routes})
  router.run(function(Handler, state) {
    var Element = React.createFactory(Handler);
    var reactHtml = React.renderToString(Element());
      return res.render('index.ejs', {reactOutput: reactHtml})
  });
});
```

Comment: I've placed `require("node-jsx").install();` at the beginning of the whole code. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. I've checked: node-jsx^0.13.3 is installed correctly.

Comment: Thank you! seems it works! I can't be sure yet, coz i didn't find the way to inject few js libraries globally. May be you know? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577850/how-to-attach-jquery-globally-without-index-html