# Syntax Error: Unexpected token < while using renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use React & React-router for server side rendering. So far, it's just a copy paste code from various sources. But I am getting syntax error (Not run-time error) when I try to run the app using node. Below is the code

**App.js**

```
'use strict';
require('babel/register');

const express        = require('express');
const http           = require('http');
const handlebars     = require('express-handlebars');
const renderToString = require('react-dom').server;
const match          = require('react-router').match;
const RoutingContext = require('react-router').RoutingContext;
const Routes         = require('./routes');
const app            = express();
var server;

// JSX transpilation
require('node-jsx').install();

// Setting up handlebars
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars({
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: 'views/server',
    partialsDir: 'views/server/partials'
}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// Mount Routes
app.use('*', function (req, res) {
    match({routes: routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
          res.status(500).send(error.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
            console.log(renderProps);
            var pageData = {
                serverHtml: renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />)
            };
            console.log(pageData);
            res.render('base', pageData);
        } else {
          res.status(404).send('Not found')
        }
    });
});

server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + 3000);
});
```

The Error that I get while running `node --harmony app.js` is

```
serverHtml: renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Do I need to install/transform(babelify/jsx) my code for processing the JSX style tags? But I didn't found any such thing stated in any tutorials online.

Resources I followed

1. [React-router(Serverside Rendering)](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md)
2. [Server Side Rendering by React](https://ifelse.io/2015/08/27/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-react-router/)

Comment: Yes, you must transform JSX into standard JS code.  JSX is not a ECMAScript standard.

Comment: Are you saying live transpiling this code & running? Like `babel-node` or something? No tutorials have mentioned this for server side rendering though

Comment: You can use `babel-node` for development.  For production, compile code using a tool before, like `react-tools`.

Comment: I have added `require('node-jsx`).install()` but still no effect. I also did add `require(babel/register)`. Taken from following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580842/react-router-server-side-error & stackoverflow.com/questions/30626410/server-side-rendering-with-react-react-router-and-express?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note** - **This method is deprecated. There are better alternative out there. As mentioned, `require('node-jsx').install()` is no longer maintained & using babel is the ideal way to go forward.**

So I fixed the issue by making few changes to the above code

I removed the following line as it is not required

```
require('babel/register');
```

Then instead of transpiling app.js via babel, I just changed the JSX tag with React.createElement() as below:

```
//serverHtml: renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />)
serverHtml: ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(RoutingContext, renderProps))
```

The full updated code is as below:

```
'use strict';

const compression    = require('compression');
const express        = require('express');
const http           = require('http');
const handlebars     = require('express-handlebars');
const path           = require('path');
const React          = require('react');
const ReactDOM       = require('react-dom/server'); // Fixed this
const match          = require('react-router').match;
const RoutingContext = require('react-router').RoutingContext;
const app            = express();
var server;

require('node-jsx').install(); // Not required if you convert the below './routes' file from JSX into js
const Routes = require('./routes');

// Used for Gzipping all the resources
app.use(compression());

// Setting up handlebars
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars({
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: 'views/server',
    partialsDir: 'views/server/partials'
}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// Set path to public assets
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Mount Routes
app.use('*', function (req, res) {
    match({routes:Routes, location:req.url}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
          res.status(500).send(error.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
            var pageData = {
                serverHtml: ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(RoutingContext, renderProps))
            };

            res.render('base', pageData);
        } else {
          res.status(404).send('Not found')
        }
    });
});

server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + 3000);
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will not work because

```
require('node-jsx').install();
```

installs a require hook to transpile files that required thenafter.

Also as others have recommended, this project is deprecated and using Babel is the best approach now.

You will have to keep your jsx in separate module and require it from your main file.

This is because the `JSX` file has to be parsed and converted to standard javascript before it reaches the javascript interpreter. In this specific case it is done by intercepting the `require` method provided by the common js runtime.

However the file that contains `require('babel/register')` can not contain JSX syntax because for that registration to occur, the file has to be run by javascript interpreter and for that to happen the file has to be parsed first. This preliminary step will fail because javascript interpreter does not recognize JSX tags.

In addition you will to use the [React preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) if you are using latest version of Babel.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get it. Are you saying I have to babelify `app.js`? I did use `require('babel/register')` at the top. I am following this article stackoverflow.com/questions/30626410/server-side-rendering-with-react-react-router-and-expres

Comment: I have updated the answer with more explanation. Let me know if some confusion still remains.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed the issue. I am using `React.createElement(RoutingContext, renderProps)` instead of JSX tags. That fixed the issue :)