# jQuery with node.js for simple things

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I installed jquery with : `npm install jquery` and then tried to run:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
console.log($('<a href="">hkjhjkh</a>').text());
```

I get this error, that I understand very well (no document in node.js!) :

```
Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" )
```

**How to make jQuery work without a `document` / `window` in `node.js` in such a simple case?**

---

*PS: I tried with: `var $=require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().createWindow());`, but unfortunately `npm install jsdom` gave me lots of make errors that I was unable to debug (that would be another question, so out of topic here).*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358015/error-jquery-requires-a-window-with-a-document

Answer (score 0):

Try cheerio (https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio):

> Fast, flexible, and lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server.

Your code would look like this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<a href="">hkjhjkh</a>');

console.log($('a').text());
```