# Using node.js with browserless jQuery via the command line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am trying to run this script below via the command line

```
var argv = require('optimist').argv,
$ = require('jquery'),
fs = require('fs');
var file = argv._[0];
var html = fs.readFileSync(file, 'UTF-8');
$(html).find('p').each(function(index) {
var content = $(this).html();
console.log('Paragraph ' + (index + 1) + ': ' + content);
}); //script.js
```

The command is `$ node script.js page.html` where `page.html` is the argument

The error I get is:

```
./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:29
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
at module.exports (./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:29:12)
...
```

I am using jquery-2.1.3. I know that this used to work, once upon a time, but it looks like something has changed.

Also I did follow the instructions at http://rkulla.blogspot.com/2014/04/using-browserify-with-jquery-backbonejs.html but I am still getting the same error.

Any help to fix this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358376/1689951). The npm package for jQuery no longer includes `jsdom`, which provides the DOM environment needed to work with jQuery on the server.

On the other hand, you could just use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), an implementation of jQuery for the server, to parse the html and use jQuery's selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var argv = require('optimist').argv,
$ = require('cheerio'),
fs = require('fs');

var file = argv._[0];
...
```

I could not install **jsdom** for the life of me so I gave up on that, but **cheerio** (`npm install` worked very smoothly after editing **package.json**) solved the problem (see code modification above). Thank you!