# How to mock library by SinonJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have a file: browser-launcher.ts

```ts
import * as Browser from "@lib/browser";
    
class BrowserLauncher {
    launch(options) {
       browser = Browser(options);
    }
}
    
export const browserLauncher = new BrowserLauncher()
```

How to mock library '@lib/browser' to test method launch of BrowserLauncher?

How to right to test variable browserLauncher in module browser-launcher.ts?

Comment: Module @lib/browser contains 1 function or 1 class?

Comment: @andreyunugro Something like that:
`
function Browser() {
//code
}

module.exports = Browser;`

Comment: Added a link to a DI example: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-198081263

Comment: Here's a proxyquire example: https://gist.github.com/fatso83/329da40002d45533b1e74db825f2bf54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinon is not really a library that deals with your specific problem, which is substituting a module for a fake one at the module loader level, as that is very specific to the environment in which you are working. Sinon only deals with the actual creation of a substitute (a mock or stub implementation). Such module *substitution* is solved by specific third party libraries such as proxyquire, rewire and the likes and the dependant module you want to replace is called a "link seam" in testing literature.

You can see a how-to by us in the Sinon team for how to do this in CommonJS environments: https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/.

Seeing the `@lib/...` string makes me think this is a webpack specific problem, in which case you should find some module replacement library that deals with webpack. One such library is [inject-loader](https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader).

That being said, *sometimes Sinon can be used to replace exports on some module*, but this is totally environment specific! Spec conforming ES Modules export an immutable namespace, so you are not *supposed* to be able to override exports.

You can see Sinon's expected behavior in our [test code](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/master/test/es2015/module-support-assessment-test.es6#L4), where you see that an export such as `export default { foo(){} }` can be stubbed (since its members are not immutable), whereas `export function foo(){}` cannot be stubbed.

The only way you can stub the exports then is by having your ES environment be non-compliant: producing exports that *are writable* or disabling the read-only nature.

**Testing the module without using link seams**

[In another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44482001/200987) I detail two ways you can use plain dependency injection to do this without external tooling. You should check that out, as it is quite straight forward, but the downside is that it will require a small test-only change to your production code to facilitate it. It's a balancing act of pros and cons: change code or introduce more dependencies.

I have written [a more elaborate example of this technique on the Sinon issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-198081263) tracker you might want to check out, where I show how to *optionally* inject the dependencies.