# How to resolve "jQuery requires a window with a document" with import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I'm getting `jQuery requires a window with a document` error and it seems that I need an answer like: [Error: jQuery requires a window with a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358015/error-jquery-requires-a-window-with-a-document)

What I'm looking for is the correct syntax for this using `import` rather than `require` because I'm not `require`-ing anything else in my Node app.  I'm trying to get this to work in a React component. I tried:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import $ from 'jquery';

jsdom.jsdom().createWindow();
```

and:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
const $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().createWindow());
```

But that's not getting me there.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: 1. you are using React. surprised to find you need jquery. in most cases you dont, see http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ 

2. require-ing vs import-ing depends on your bundler and what it can resolve and how it can resolve it. take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery for how to include jquery for your bundler. 

3. it seems like your issue is more cosmetic that it is a real issue, if require works, I'd go with that.

Comment: As @AhmedMusallam said, `require` might be better for you. Have you tried: `const $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().createWindow());` ?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This only works for older versions of jsdom.

I do this for the [tests for using jQuery Mockjax in a Node context](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/blob/master/test/nodejs/test.js). Essentially, I use the jsdom `env()` method to generate the window object with a blank HTML document:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
let $;

jsdom.env('<html></html>', function (error, window) {
    if (error) {
        // handle this somehow
    } else {
        $ = require('jquery')(window);
        // now you have it...
    }
});
```

Comment: (Obviously I'm not using ES6 `import`s, but I think you can get to a solution from what I have.)

Comment: "_jsdom2.default.env is not a function"  Thanks, but I get this error.

Comment: Ah... I'm on a really old version. ;)