# find css classes from html string

Tags: css, regex

I have an HTML string which contains, among CSS and HTML markup, some tags with CSS classes. How do I get the collection of classes?
I'd like to do:

```
htmlString.replace(patternForEveryClass, "somePrefix_"+capturedGroupIndex);
```

where the pattern must collect all classes into a tag, and `capturedGroupIndex` must be the index of the captured class.

This is the regex I have right now:

`class="((\s|[a-zA-Z_-]{1}[\w-_]+)+)"`

https://regex101.com/r/pI9nX2/2

Is there a way to collect all instances within the `class=""` attribute? I cannot use DOM JS, just string scrapping.

Comment: Is your code JavaScript or do you use some other language for this? Also, why can't you use the DOM?

Comment: [You can't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: I'm using nodejs. I'm reading html files and doing some modifications to html markups. This has to be in server, not in browser.

Comment: Well, you can use [jQuery in NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4129032/3764814), it's a much better solution than regexes.