# Webstorm 10.0.3 + "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: jquery, node.js, webstorm, handlebars.js

I wanted to use JQuery within Webstorm, but as soon as I use something like `$("*")` I get an error(when working in a JS-file):

```
console.log($("*"));
```

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>           at ...\app.js:41:21
>           at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
>       Process finished with exit code 1

What I did so far is I included the jquery file in my layout-page(master page) in the head section and it works.

Under Settings and Libraries I checked JQuery.

But I still got that error, I think I have to change some settings in Webstorm...?!

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: As I see - you run your script and got an error. That is mean that $ is undefined at your script. Did you include jquery file like "var $ = require('jquery')" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you takl about checking at WebStrom - add at the begining of file

```
/* global $ */
```

Read more at http://usejsdoc.org/tags-global.html

And if you talk about running program - you should include file where $ defined

Comment: I get the same error...when I use /* global $ */ or /** @global */

Comment: As I see - you run your script and got an error. That is mean that $ is undefined at your script. Did you include jquery file like "var $ = require('jquery')" or something else?

Comment: now I get this: "module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (..e.js:6:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

Process finished with exit code 1"

Comment: Of course. It was just example. What do you what to do with jquery at server side?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js

Comment: I want to list all files in a folder and then use the result in a template(handlebars) https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/how-to-list-files-and-folders-using-nodejs/

Comment: I'm not sure than $ is jQuery in that case

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at [jsdom module](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) if you like to do smth like this using Node.js. See usage examples in readme