# Please suggest a backend based on jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, express

I know jQuery & Java. I want to build a backend for my android app. I don't want to learn Javascript right now. Can I make backend via Express.js with only jQuery knowledge? Or is there any backend service like Express.js based totally on jQuery?

Comment: javascript backend??

Comment: _I don't want to learn Javascript right now_ but you want to use express and jquery :))

Comment: I think something like nodejs

Comment: @Alessandro he doesn't want to learn javascript

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js) anyway to use JQuery you should already know javascript

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. If you want to use JavaScript libraries and frameworks, you **MUST** learn JavaScript. jQuery does not exist on the server side, but you could use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. They were all very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery is browser based. If you are dealing with JSON objects then it would be easy to use Express.js which is a library commonly used with Node.js. You cannot use JQuery to code backend.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use jQuery for backend development and you can't use it with express.js, it's limited to frontend.

Generally if you already know jQuery, plain javascript will be easy to pick up. And you generally don't need a very high level of javascript knowledge to get started with express.js atleast.

I'd suggest an hour of codecademy or something of the like to get to grips with the syntax.