# Nodejs Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined after var jQuery = require('jquery');

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I installed jQuery and it is not my question:

```
npm install jquery
```

I try to include jQuery library into my page like this:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery'); or
import jQuery from "jquery";
```

and get in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

How can I overcome it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

Comment: Did you try `import {jQuery, $} from "jquery";`?

Answer (score 6):

You have to use:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

or

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Answer (score 2):

In my cases the following works well:

```
global.jQuery   = require('jquery');
global.$        = global.jQuery;
```

or if you prefer "window" or it is obviously present, then:

```
typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this;
window.jQuery   = require('jquery');
window.$        = window.jQuery;
```