# Unable to use jQuery globally

Tags: node.js

I want to be able to use jQuery in all my js files. I've downloaded the jQuery & jsdom modules through npm.

I've been incorporating my code into my app.js file.
I've tried both:

```
global.$ = require('jquery')(global.window);
```

and

```
var varjsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
global.$ = require('jquery/dist/jquery')(jsdom().createWindow());
```

to no avail. How am I meant to get global permission to use jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind jQuery to any window object you create with jsDom otherwise your jQuery symbol is simply not bound to anything at all.