# How to convert a working curl/jquery.ajax call onto the backend in Node/Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, curl, axios

I'm a first time question asker here, my apologies in advance if I make any mistakes in this process.  Thank you for your time and assistance in advance.

My end goal is to to use a Node/Express server to access photos from the [Webdam.com](http://www.webdam.com) API. The API docs provide a working CURL command which I converted into a jQuery.ajax() http call that I tested in my browser.  I wish to convert the working jQuery.ajax() call into code on a Node/Express server in order to protect my API keys.

In the end I hope to use something along the lines of [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) but I'm open to other options.  I've looked into using jQuery on my Node server as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js), but it appears these code examples are deprecated and because jQuery needs a window.document to work, it seems to me Axios or Request would be a better way to go.

Some background info about the working jQuery.ajax() http call, I first retrieve an Oauth2 token.  After I receive a token, I make another jQuery.ajax() call to retrieve the Webdam photo content, API docs are [here](https://www.damsuccess.com/hc/en-us/articles/202134055-REST-API#api_get_token_password).

Would someone assist me please in converting this jQuery.ajax() code into Node/Express code so I can retrieve a OAuth2 token.

WORKING CURL COMMAND:

`curl -X POST https://apiv2.webdamdb.com/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_KEY&username=USERNAME&password=USER_PASSWORD'`

WORKING JQUERY.AJAX() CALL:

```js
 var params = {
  grant_type: 'password',
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: SECRET_KEY,
  username: USERNAME,
  password: USER_PASSWORD
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://apiv2.webdamdb.com/oauth2/token',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: params,
  success: function(response) {
    return response.access_token;
  },
  error: function(error) {
    return 'ERROR in webdamAuthenticate';
  }
});
```

AXIOS ATTEMP THAT IS NOT WORKING:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const params = {
  grant_type: 'password',
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: SECRET_KEY,
  username: USERNAME,
  password: USER_PASSWORD
};

axios.post('https://apiv2.webdamdb.com/oauth2/token/', params)
  .then(response => {
    console.log('success in axios webdamAuth', response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR in axios webdamAuth ');
  });
```

This is the error response I get, I thought I was specifying the grant_type but it tells me I am not.  I have Googled the error but don't understand what I am missing, please help.

```js
{ error: 'invalid_request',
  error_description: 'The grant type was not specified in the request' }
400
{ date: 'Mon, 04 Dec 2017 19:19:34 GMT',
  server: 'Apache',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=86400; includeSubDomains',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT',
  'cache-control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'content-length': '97',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you working curl command it sends `POST` data with default format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To encode your form url-encode your data in axios you can refer to [this](https://github.com/axios/axios#nodejs).

For instance :

```
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');

var params = {
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: SECRET_KEY,
    username: USERNAME,
    password: USER_PASSWORD
};

axios.post(
    'https://apiv2.webdamdb.com/oauth2/token', 
    querystring.stringify(params), {
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'YourApp'
        }
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you for your reply, I appreciate your time.  I'm still curious about the key/value pair meaning inside the headers property?