# dts-gen ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to generate the definition file for jquery-colorbox. I use from my project root:

```
dts-gen -m jquery-colorbox
```

which fails with:

```
Unexpected crash! Please log a bug with the commandline you specified.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dts-gen/bin/lib/run.js:130
        throw e;
        ^

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adr/Projects/albums/node_modules/jquery-colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js:1105:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dts-gen/bin/lib/run.js:57:67)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
```

I do have jQuery and other required libraries installed (globally and locally). How do I "tell" dts-gen to "load" / "use" jQuery?

Comment: You may want to know that there is already a type declaration package available for `jquery-colorbox` under the name [`@types/jquery.colorbox`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery.colorbox).

Comment: good to know, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that `dts-gen` needs to actually load the module you specify in order to examine its structure, and `jquery-colorbox` expects `jQuery`, `document`, and `window` to be defined on the global object, which they aren't in Node.js.  One possible approach (which I didn't pursue) is to use `dts-gen`'s experimental support for [browser-based generation of declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dts-gen#browser).  Another is to load a Node.js-compatible DOM implementation such as `jsdom` and set the necessary global variables so that you can load `jquery-colorbox` successfully.  Specifically, if you write the following in a file named `jquery-colorbox-wrapper.js` (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129032)):

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
global.document = document;
global.window = window;
require("jquery-colorbox");
```

and then run `dts-gen --expression-file jquery-colorbox-wrapper.js`, it should run successfully.

Then you'll run into the second problem: the generated declaration file is empty because `jquery-colorbox`, as a jQuery plugin, adds things to the jQuery object and does not have exports of its own.  If you change the wrapper script to return the jQuery object, then you'll get the declarations for `jquery-colorbox` mixed with those of jQuery itself.  A reasonable approach is to diff the declaration files that you get for jQuery with and without `jquery-colorbox`.  I.e., append `global.jQuery;` to the `jquery-colorbox-wrapper.js` file as given above, run `dts-gen` once, then comment out the `require("jquery-colorbox");` line and run `dts-gen` again with a different output file, and finally diff the two files.  That leaves me with the `jquery-colorbox`-specific declarations as well as some diffs in `sizzle*` variables whose names contain a timestamp, which should be easy to remove.  Of course, the declaration file will need significant cleanup.