# node can't load app because it doesn't recognise jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Node to debug a Javascript file that contains some JQuery. but when loading files it gets not recognized on $.
I've installed JQuery to local package (`npm install jquery -save-dev`).

"`npm jquery -version`" result is 6.9.8

**Code**:

```
$("#modalAddRole").on("modal:visible", function () {
    $("#roleName").val("");
    $("#roleName").focus();
});
```

Comment: is it possible to add "jquery syntax" to node?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

Comment: @TheRuler — There's no such thing as 'jQuery syntax'. jQuery is just a collection of objects written in regular JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @Quentin and this collection is the syntax. but please have your opiniion

Comment: @TheRuler — It's not an opinion. Syntax has a specific meaning.

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry but discussing this isn't on the top of my list. if you believe jQuery is not syntax, good for you

Comment: You don't want to use node for this. You want to use your browser console.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) manipulates the dom.

node.js does not have a dom.

You'll need to create a virtual dom (that does not display)

for that use **[jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)** to load your webpage/app and then execute whatever dom manipulation code you want.

**Example:**

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
const jquery = require('jquery');

JSDOM.fromURL("https://url_To_Your_WebPage_Local_Or_Remote.com")
  .then(dom => {
    const $ = jquery(dom.window);
    //your jQuery code here
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've installed JQuery to local package

Installing it isn't enough. You need to load it into your program…

```
const $ = require('jquery');
```

… and then `$("#modalAddRole")` isn't going to do anything until you load your HTML into it.

See [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery):

> For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required.
>   Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by
>   tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes.
>
> ```
> require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
>     if (err) {
>         console.error(err);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     var $ = require("jquery")(window);
> });
> ```

---

But this seems like a very complicated approach to getting a debugging environment running. Assuming the production environment for the code in the browser, it would make a lot more sense to debug it **in the browser**.

Browsers have excellent debugging tools built-in these days, and simulating all the things browsers do by default is likely to make debugging harder because the debug environment is signficantly different to the production environment.

Comment: I usually used the browser for debugging, but always curious about other methods